# jQuery - Using .one() with hover

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to get a hover function to only execute once? This is what I'm currently trying:

```
$('#ask').live('hover', function() {

    $('#homesearch-after').hide(300);

    $.doTimeout( 300, function() {
        hideClosedSearchLink();
        showHomeSearch();
    });

});
```

But that's not working. How can I only get this hover to activate once?

I've tried changing .live with .one and .bind... resulting in nothingness.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you can get rid of the timeout by adding the code inside it directly as a callback after the `hide` finishes: `$('#homesearch-after').hide(300, function() {/** code here **/});`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've already answered yourself, use `.one()` (not `.live()`).

But as lasseespeholt just pointed out in a comment, `.hover()` is shorthand for binding to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, and is not an event in itself.

Try this:

```
$('#ask').one('mouseenter', function() {

    $('#homesearch-after').hide(300);

    $.doTimeout( 300, function() {
        hideClosedSearchLink();
        showHomeSearch();
    });

});
```

If that still doesn't work, try just using the good ol' `.hover()` and then `.unbind()`ing it immediately after it's finished.

```
$('#ask').hover(function() {

    $('#homesearch-after').hide(300);

    $.doTimeout( 300, function() {
        hideClosedSearchLink();
        showHomeSearch();
    });

    // Again taking into account what lasseespeholt said
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')

});
```

Comment: @Jared: Is your `#ask` being added dynamically to your page by JS?

Comment: No, it is displayed with static HTML.

Comment: I guess it have to be a JavaScript event, and I don't think "hover" is. So try something like "mousemove" or "mouseover".

Comment: I see how that makes sense, but strangely enough it's still not working... If I remove all that stuff above and just use .hover, it all works just fine. This is quite confusing. :P

Comment: I figured it out, thanks! I am dumb and didn't put it inside $(window).load(function() {  }); lol - thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

[`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is not a real `event` but a shorthand method that binds handlers for two events, [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave), and as such doesn't work with [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) (as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/GZdtA/)). To replicate the behavior of `hover` you'd have to have two binds that will both trigger only one time, like this:

```
$("#foo").one("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("bar");
});
```

The above would be the same as the following, with the exception that it fires only once:

```
$("#foo").hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("bar");
});
```

If you want to do different things on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, you need to bind separate handlers:

```
$("#foo").one("mouseenter", function(e){
    $(this).addClass("bar").text("Over");
}).one("mouseleave", function(e){
    $(this).removeClass("bar").text("Out");
});
```

What I can read from your code is that you are only looking to bind the `mouseenter` event, like this:

```
$('#ask').one('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#homesearch-after').hide(300);
    $.doTimeout( 300, function() {
        hideClosedSearchLink();
        showHomeSearch();
    });
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, `.one('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {...)`

Comment: @BoltClock, that's even better if you are looking to do a `toggle` of sorts, like in my example. I'll add it!