# How do I make an AJAX call only once on JQuery.hover()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jquery-hover

I would like to display the results of an AJAX call in a div when the user hovers over it (i.e. replace the div contents with the results of the AJAX call).  The basic functionality is to replace a dot on the page with a circle that contains content from the server when the user hovers over the dot, and show the dot again when they stop hovering.  There may be many dots on the page, each with different circle content on hover.

I have it working, but I notice that the AJAX call is getting repeatedly called while the user is hovering over the given div.  How can I prevent repeated calls?

I have tried various usages of `.one` and `.unbind('mouseenter', 'mouseleave')` but haven't gotten it to work right yet.

Here's what I have right now (the hover behavior works right for the user but causes repeated calls to the backend).

```
<div class="box1" s='<%=value1 %>' t='<%=value2 %>'>
   <div id="circle" style="display: none;">
   </div>
   <div class="dot" id="dot">
      <img src="orangeDot.png" />
   </div>
</div>
```

and the script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".box1").hover(function () {
            var source = $(this).attr('s');
            var target = $(this).attr('t');
            $('#dot').attr("style", "display: none;");
            $('#circle').hide().load('/GetCircle?s=' + source + '&t=' + target).show();
        }, function () {
            $('#circle' + divid).attr("style", "display: none;");
            $('#dot' + divid).attr("style", "display: inline-block;");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: To clarify, you want the hover action to happen on _every_ hover, but want to retrieve the content for an individual element from the server only once, reusing it on the next hover?

Comment: Yes, this exactly what I want to happen.

Comment: Okey dokey, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just have a boolean flag like `var ajaxed = false` and switch it to true after the request is completed once? Then just wrap your hover action in a check for `ajaxed`.

Comment: A variation on this worked for me -- basically since I have multiple divs that call the same script on hover I used an array of div identifiers to track which had been run, and only re-run if the current div isn't in the array.  I'll post my answer below.  Thanks.

Comment: You can also use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to set a flag directly on each element and avoid iterating through the array.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using `mouseover` instead of hover.  You could do some actions when it's moused over, such as unbinding it from the action.  And you could bind it again on a `mouseout`.

The idea is to unbind the mouseover action when the mouseover function is called. This removes the mouseover function from the element that was hovered.  I didn't test this...I apologize if it isn't exactly correct.

```
$(ele).mouseover(function() {
   $(this).unbind('mouseover');
});
```

Comment: Good idea - I've tried this in a way but I'm not too familiar with bind and unbind so I'm not sure I was doing it right.  Can you offer some specifics on how it would work?

Comment: That's the same as using `.one()`, and isn't what the OP was actually asking (I wasn't sure myself until I asked him exactly what he meant)

Answer (score 1):

adding a loaded attribute on the fly is the best I found.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".box1").hover(function () {
            var source = $(this).attr('s');
            var target = $(this).attr('t');
            var $circle = $('#circle' + divid);
            $('#dot').attr("style", "display: none;");
            if ( $circle.data('loaded') == 'yes' ) {
                $circle.show();
            }
            else {
                $.get('/GetCircle', {s: source, t: target}, function (data) {
                    $circle.data('loaded', 'yes');
                    $circle.html(data); // note: "$circle.get(0).innerHTML = data" is faster
                    $circle.show(); // of course, the 3 methods can be chained 
                }};
            }, function () {
                $('#circle' + divid).hide(); // was ".attr("style", "display: none;");"
                $('#dot' + divid).attr("style", "display: inline-block;");
            }):
        });
    });
</script>
```

note: add and removing classes (previously defined in your CSS) is faster. example: $(obj).removeClass('invisible').addClass('inlineBlock')

Comment: +1 indeed, though I would not use `.attr()` for the flag, nor would I use class adjustments or css display for showing hiding--let jQuery handle what's best there (via `.show()`/`.hide()`), IMO.

Comment: when you have 10k+ elements that can be shown or hidden, it does matter, but else I agree. But what would you use for the flag then? (an array of loaded elements, and check against it with indexOf ?)

Comment: `.data()` for the flag. At worst, `.prop()`

Comment: thanx!! edited. (but you have not to confuse it the data returned by xhr)

Comment: No problem.  When my ajax requests are asking for HTML, I name the parameter to the success function `html`.  (See my answer)

Comment: indeed, I always thought it would work, but I never bothered to try ^^

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response to my question in the comment to your OP, I would adjust your entire sample as posted below (untested).  The general idea is to do nothing if the ajax is awaiting response (try to avoid race condition), to get content and use it if it hasn't been flagged as having already been done, or just adjust the showing/hiding. Some adjustment for your preferences and integration may be necessary.

```
<div class="box" data-s="<%=value1 %>" data-t="<%=value2 %>">
    <div class="circle" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div class="dot">
        <img src="orangeDot.png" alt="orange dot" />
    </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $( function()
    {
        var IN_FLIGHT = 'requestinflight',
            RETRIEVED = 'contentretrieved';

        $( '.box' ).hover(
            function()
            {
                var $box, $circle, $dot;

                $box = $( this );

                if( ! $box.data( IN_FLIGHT ) )
                {
                    $dot = $box.find( '.dot' );
                    $circle = $box.find( '.circle' );

                    if( ! $box.data( RETRIEVED ) )
                    {
                        $box.data( IN_FLIGHT, true );
                        $.ajax( {
                            url: '/GetCircle',
                            data: {
                                s: $box.data( 's' ),
                                t: $box.data( 't' )
                            }
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function( html )
                            {
                                $box.data( RETRIEVED, true );
                                $circle.html( html ).show();
                                $dot.hide();
                            },
                            complete: function()
                            {
                                $box.data( IN_FLIGHT, false );
                            }
                        } );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $circle.show();
                        $dot.hide();
                    }
                }
            },
            function()
            {
                var $box = $( this );
                if( ! $box.data( IN_FLIGHT ) )
                {
                    $box.find( '.circle' ).hide();
                    $box.find( '.dot' ).show();
                }
            }
        );
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery `one('hover', function() {...});`

http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".box1").one('hover',function () {
                var source = $(this).attr('s');
                var target = $(this).attr('t');
                $('#dot').attr("style", "display: none;");
                $('#circle').hide().load('/GetCircle?s=' + source + '&t=' + target).show();
            }, function () {
                $('#circle' + divid).attr("style", "display: none;");
                $('#dot' + divid).attr("style", "display: inline-block;");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work - this post addresses why (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638691/jquery-using-one-with-hover).  I've tried combinations with mouseenter and mouseleave but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It doesn't work because it kills the hove after it happened once.  You still want the hover, you just don't want to re-retrieve the content from the server.