# Get and set the height and width of elements on hover only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

On hover, the following code gets the tallest column in a submenu panel and sets all columns to the same height.  It also gets the sum of the width of all columns and sets the column container width to the sum:

```
$(function() 
{
    $("#menu> li").hover(function () {
        var tallestColumnHeight = 0, submenuPanelTotalWidth = 0;
        $("ul.sub-menu-1 > li", this).each(function () {
            tallestColumnHeight = Math.max(tallestColumnHeight, $(this).height());
            submenuPanelTotalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(), 10);
        }).height(tallestColumnHeight);
        $("ul.sub-menu-1 > li", this).parent().width( submenuPanelTotalWidth );
   });  
});
```

Right now the code above has a lot of overhead as it gets and sets the height and width twice on each hover.  I want to set some kind of flag so that the calculations only run once.

Any ideas?  Is it wise to use jQuery .data() here to store the initial values once and then check if the data is set?

Any suggestions or help with this is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Replacing hover() with the mouseenter() event and using one() was the best solution.

Here is the updated code:

```
$(function() 
{
$("#menu > li").one('mouseenter', function(e)   
{
    var tallestColumnHeight = 0,
        submenuPanelTotalWidth = 0;

    $("ul.sub-menu-1 > li", this).each(function ()
    {
        tallestColumnHeight = Math.max(tallestColumnHeight, $(this).height());
        submenuPanelTotalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(true), 10);
    }).height(tallestColumnHeight);

    $("ul.sub-menu-1 > li", this).parent().width( submenuPanelTotalWidth );     
}); 
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .one() function of jquery. Unfortunately, hover is not a real event. Instead it should be replaced as .one("mouseenter mouseleave",function()...

Comment: Seems like already discussed in SO. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638691/jquery-using-one-with-hover

Comment: Thanks Raghav, replacing hover with mouseenter and using .one() was the best approach.  Updated my post with new code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu> li").hover(function (){


//your code

$("#menu> li").unbind('hover')
});
```

Use this code, provided you dont have any other function bound to hover function. This unbind technique removes the function associated with the hover event.

Answer (score 0):

You could save your eventHandler function in a variable and call unbind on the element with the saved variable. This would be more performant as the handler function won´t get executed anymore.

```
$(function()  {

  var hoverFunction = function () {
    var tallestColumnHeight = 0,
    submenuPanelTotalWidth = 0;

    $("ul.sub-menu-1 > li", this).each(function () {
      tallestColumnHeight = Math.max(tallestColumnHeight, $(this).height());
      submenuPanelTotalWidth += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(), 10);
    }).height(tallestColumnHeight);

    $("ul.sub-menu-1 > li", this).parent().width( submenuPanelTotalWidth );
    $("#menu> li").unbind('hover', hoverFunction);
  };

  $("#menu> li").hover();  
});
```